# Can i show my app view at main activity as live wallpaper?

Tags: clock, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

I am making a clock application, and I want the appearance of the application in the main activity to appear as a live wallpaper and the application can run when Android starts and runs on background.
Can i di that things?

I just finished making the digital clock app, and I can't figure out how to set it as a live wallpaper